# Why doesn't tensorflow run on Python 3.8?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried installing TensorFlow on my Mac, running Python 3.8 and was stumped with the following error upon trying to verify its installation:

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random'
```

I've now downgraded Python to 3.6.0 and it's working correctly. What's in `Python 3.8` that was blocking TensorFlow?

Comment: What did you do to `verify its installation`. Can you post the code you have tried and the **full** error message

Comment: Tensorflow has some issues with python new version.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374#issuecomment-581477645

Comment: The [installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) specifies that only Python 3.5 to 3.7 is supported at the moment, and there are only [PyPI packages](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.1.0/#files) for those versions.

Comment: you can try installing it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

In this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip you can see that Tensorflow is only supported till python 3.7 as of now.

**System requirements**
  -Python 3.5–3.7
  -pip 19.0 or later (requires manylinux2010 support)
  -Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit)
  -macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (64-bit) (no GPU support)
  -Windows 7 or later (64-bit) (Python 3 only)
  -Raspbian 9.0 or later
  -GPU support requires a CUDA®-enabled card (Ubuntu and Windows)

and at the last of page you can see what are the supported python packages with tensorflow.